# SplitMotionEvents not disabling multi tou

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, multi-touch

so I'm currently working on trying to disable multi touch on an activity so users can't click the on and off button at the same time. Through my research I saw that others have been able to do this by setting `android:splitMotionEvents` to false. Like I've done below

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:splitMotionEvents="false"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    tools:context="com.gm.hmi.presentation.ttysetting.TTYSettingOverviewActivity">
```

However, when I run it in the emulator I'm still able to simulate multi touch. Do I need to add anything else? Or is there something I'm missing? Thank you for your help